# What would happen when transaction and orphan pools is full?

Tags: mining-pools

Since mining nodes has memory limitations, what would happen if transaction and orphan pools is full?

If the nodes need to drop certain transactions, how does the nodes choose which transaction to drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those paying the lowest feerate are dropped, working similarly to the transaction selection logic for blocks which prioritizes transactions that have the highest feerate.

Comment: So can an incoming orphan tx with higher fees displace a transaction in the regular tx pool, or will it only replace a transaction in the orphan tx pool?